# Automapper flattening not behaving as expected

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to flatted out a nested object. All of the documentation and stack threads seem to suggest the solution is very simple, but it just isn't working.

Consider the following (simplified) objects:

```
public class CRouteHold
{
    public int HoldId { get; set; }
    public virtual Hold? Hold { get; set; }
    public bool? fhandstart { get; set; }
    public bool? ffootstart { get; set; }
    public bool? rhandstart { get; set; }
    public bool? rfootstart { get; set; }
}

public class Hold
{
    public double? xpos { get; set; }
}
```

and then a flat Dto I want to map to:

```
public record CRouteHoldDto(
    int HoldId,
    bool fhandstart,
    bool ffootstart,
    bool rhandstart,
    bool rfootstart,
    double xpos
 );
```

Now, I've tried a bunch of mapping profiles, some work and some don't. The one I want to work and which seems like it should work doesn't. Here's what I've tried.

1. Simple unflatted setup: If I comment out the xpos on the dto and just map the 'root' layer of the RouteHold object like so:

   ```
   CreateMap<CRouteHold, CRouteHoldDto>();
   ```

This works, and gives a `CRouteHoldDto`.

2. Flattening setup using a naming convention - if I change the name of `xpos` on the dto to `HoldXpos` (camelcase of ObjectProperty) then automapper figures it out and maps the `xpos` from the child Hold on `CRouteHold` to the `HoldXpos` property. The mapping profile is the same as above. Nothing needs to change.
3. Flatting without naming convention, using `ForMember` - I don't want the long `HoldXpos` name on my Dto. I just want `xpos`, the same as on the child `Hold`. To do this, the documentation and a myriad of Stack threads seem to suggest I can use a mapping profile like this:

   ```
   CreateMap<CRouteHold, CRouteHoldDto>()
   .ForMember(rh => rh.xpos, m => m.MapFrom(rh => rh.Hold.xpos));
   ```

However, it just doesn't seem to work. It throws an error about needing an empty constructor or optional args.

Am I missing something here?

Edit: From comments I also tried using the IncludeMembers by creating an additional map from Hold to CRouteHoldDto:

```
CreateMap<CRouteHold, CRouteHoldDto>()
.IncludeMembers(s => s.Hold);
CreateMap<Hold, CRouteHoldDto>(MemberList.None);
```

Unfortuantely, the result is the same.

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to @LucianBargaoanu. For those in the future, the exact mapping profile now looks like this:

```
CreateMap<CRouteHold, CRouteHoldDto>()
.ForCtorParam("xpos", m => m.MapFrom(s => s.Hold.xpos))
.ForCtorParam("otherproperty", m => m.MapFrom(s => s.Hold.otherproperty))
```

So just keep adding on the ForCtorParam for each property you want to map.

Comment: _"Am I missing something here?"_ Yes! What if `rh.Hold` is `null`?

Comment: Also mind that all your Entity props are nullable, while your DTO props are not.

Comment: I'm running a unit test where it definitely isn't null. Is simple the fact that it could be null enough to make this not work? I assumed if it was null, automapper would just map a null value? I've changed the nullability to various different combos, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: It cannot map `null` to a `bool`. The best it can do is map `default`.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers

Comment: Nullability doesn't seem to make a difference. The bool fields are nullable and they map fine. If I remove nullability from everything, it still doesn't map ONLY when trying to map xpos from the child Hold object.

Comment: `IncludeMembers` does work, but you need to enable only public constructors. So it's easier to simply use `ForCtorParam` instead of `ForMember`.

Comment: Amazing! thanks, ForCtorParam works a treat :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `ForCtorParam` instead of `ForMember`. A record is immutable, so in fact you're doing constructor mapping.

See https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Construction.html.